# How can I get the second to last item in a Kotlin List?

Tags: list, kotlin

Let's say I have a List in Kotlin like:

```
val lst = MutableList<Int>()
```

If I want the last item, I can do lst.last(), but what about the second to last?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
val secondLast = lst.dropLast(1).last()
```

:-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the size of the list to compute the index of the item you want.

For example, the last item in the list is `lst[lst.size - 1]`.

The second to last item in the list is `lst[lst.size - 2]`.

The third to last item in the list is `lst[lst.size - 3]`.

And so on.

Be sure the list is large enough to have an n'th to last item, otherwise you will get an index error

Answer (score 1):

Use Collections Slice

```
val list = mutableListOf("one" , "two" , "three")
print(list.slice(1..list.size - 1))
```

This will give you the following result
`[two, three]`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have 5 items in your `val lst = MutableList<Int>()` and you want to access the second last, it means listObject[3](list start with 0th index).

```
lst.add(101) - 0th Index
lst.add(102) - 1th Index
lst.add(103) - 2th Index
lst.add(104) - 3th Index
lst.add(105) - 4th Index
```

So you can try this

```
last[lst.size - 2] = 104 3rd Index
```

`lst.size` return 5, so if you use `size - 1` it means you try to access last index 4th one, but when you use `size - 2` it means you try to access the second last index 3rd.

Answer (score 0):

Take secondLast element with null check,

```
fun <T> List<T>.secondLast(): T {
if (size < 2)
    throw NoSuchElementException("List has less than two elements")
return this[size - 2]}
```

or use this, It simply return null if the index size does not match

```
myList.getOrNull(myList.lastIndex - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slice and until in Kotlin.

```kotlin
lst.slice(1 until lst.size)
```

Answer (score -1):

drop first
`lst.drop(1)`

take from last
`lst.takeLast(lst.size - 1 )`

slice from..to
`lst.slice(1..(lst.size-1) )`

You may refer to this link https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-parts.html